# How can I access the scripts in the /bin/ folder of a Python library I imported with pip?

Tags: python, git, pip

I'm self taught in python and don't have a ton of experience with using outside libraries or anything.

I am using PyCharm and I imported the [TGS](https://gitlab.com/mattia.basaglia/tgs/) library to my project's virtual environment. I can access and import the main modules from the lib/tgs folder without any problem. But there's a /bin/ folder in the root directory on the GitLab page that has scripts in it. I need to know how to access those scripts in my own project. Is there any way to call or import those scripts or do I need to just copy the file I want to my own project and then use it that way?

Sorry if this is a noob question I just haven't been able to figure it out on my own or find it online. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some solutions of your problem in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: The content of the `bin` folder should have been copied to a directory in your PATH, try calling them from the command line

Comment: The content of the `bin` folder should have been copied to a directory in your PATH, try calling them from the command line